# Why are boilerplate extensions provided in Alamofire's readme not just included in the project

Tags: ios, swift, macos, alamofire

I'm trying to understand why the popular Swift networking library [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) has a bunch of code snippets that seem to me at least could be included in the project.  No doubt there is an intelligent reason they aren't hence the question.

In my experience of using the library I copy the snippets into a file in the project where they live alone and just extend the functionality of the Alamofire library.

These particular snippets provide protocols and generic functionality to make serialising custom objects from an http response simple to implement.

Cheers for any insights :-D

Please see below for the snippets I'm referring to.

```
protocol ResponseObjectSerializable {
    init?(response: HTTPURLResponse, representation: Any)
}

extension DataRequest {
    func responseObject<T: ResponseObjectSerializable>(
        queue: DispatchQueue? = nil,
        completionHandler: @escaping (DataResponse<T>) -> Void)
        -> Self
    {
        let responseSerializer = DataResponseSerializer<T> { request, response, data, error in
            guard error == nil else { return .failure(BackendError.network(error: error!)) }

            let jsonResponseSerializer = DataRequest.jsonResponseSerializer(options: .allowFragments)
            let result = jsonResponseSerializer.serializeResponse(request, response, data, nil)

            guard case let .success(jsonObject) = result else {
                return .failure(BackendError.jsonSerialization(error: result.error!))
            }

            guard let response = response, let responseObject = T(response: response, representation: jsonObject) else {
                return .failure(BackendError.objectSerialization(reason: "JSON could not be serialized: \(jsonObject)"))
            }

            return .success(responseObject)
        }

        return response(queue: queue, responseSerializer: responseSerializer, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}


protocol ResponseCollectionSerializable {
    static func collection(from response: HTTPURLResponse, withRepresentation representation: Any) -> [Self]
}

extension ResponseCollectionSerializable where Self: ResponseObjectSerializable {
    static func collection(from response: HTTPURLResponse, withRepresentation representation: Any) -> [Self] {
        var collection: [Self] = []

        if let representation = representation as? [[String: Any]] {
            for itemRepresentation in representation {
                if let item = Self(response: response, representation: itemRepresentation) {
                    collection.append(item)
                }
            }
        }

        return collection
    }
}

extension DataRequest {
    @discardableResult
    func responseCollection<T: ResponseCollectionSerializable>(
        queue: DispatchQueue? = nil,
        completionHandler: @escaping (DataResponse<[T]>) -> Void) -> Self
    {
        let responseSerializer = DataResponseSerializer<[T]> { request, response, data, error in
            guard error == nil else { return .failure(BackendError.network(error: error!)) }

            let jsonSerializer = DataRequest.jsonResponseSerializer(options: .allowFragments)
            let result = jsonSerializer.serializeResponse(request, response, data, nil)

            guard case let .success(jsonObject) = result else {
                return .failure(BackendError.jsonSerialization(error: result.error!))
            }

            guard let response = response else {
                let reason = "Response collection could not be serialized due to nil response."
                return .failure(BackendError.objectSerialization(reason: reason))
            }

            return .success(T.collection(from: response, withRepresentation: jsonObject))
        }

        return response(responseSerializer: responseSerializer, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}
```